# printing every nth string of characters to new file

Tags: command-line, printing

I have a file named 'test' and it contains a string of character looking like this:

lqjzpvfyimberiaznkerbdozuqtwysbnxftldcze oukasyjelpnsiujsjaeotcqtivvadno

My goal is too get every 7th string of character and have it in a new file called 'result'.

The 'result' file should print this word: linux oesi

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: This sounds like an assignment question - have you tried anything yourself? BTW your expected result isn't consistent with the description (remember 'space' is a character)

Comment: Are you positive about the input file contents and expected results and that you want every 7th character of input?   Your Input's 1st character is "l" (el ) and its 8th character is "y"... your expected output indicates the second character should be "i" (eye)... which is the ninth character of input.

Comment: You are right, sorry didn't write my post correctly.

Comment: @NeoCapo then perhaps you should edit your post with an addendum containing the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

It would be convenient for you to read about the cut command.

Specifically what you require is something like:

```
cut -c 7,14,21,28 test > result
```

Comment: Hi, 

if there a way to do it without putting 7,14,21,28... etc ?
Imagine my string of character being longer than this.

Thank you for you help !

Comment: +1 for printing "gnu" when executed on the alphabet, even though this was obviously not the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a simple loop. However, the example provided is not matching the answer...

```
c=1; while (( $c < $(wc -c test | cut -f1 -d ' ') )); do  head test -c $c | tail -c 1 ; c=$(($c+7)); done
```